# Springboot Convert String to JavaMoney

Tags: spring-boot, java-money

I have one client that post into my service currency just like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"amount": "12.323,44"
}
```

how can configure my springboot to convert this in a java money field? 
this is my object

```
public class MyObject {
  private Long id;
  private Money amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked for spring boot, and seems to be how to automatically convert while mapping in MVC, you are looking for `@InitBinder` coupled with `@ControllerAdvice`.

An example used is here in this S.O article [What is the purpose of init binder in spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211323/what-is-the-purpose-of-init-binder-in-spring-mvc).

Write a biding method to covert the string to money or any other object as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Using jackson custom deserializer

```
@JsonComponent
publi class MoneyJsonDeserializer 
  extends JsonDeserializer<Money> {

    @Override
    public Money deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
      DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        TreeNode treeNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        TextNode amountNode = (TextNode) treeNode.get(
          "amount");
        return new Money(amountNode.asText());
    }
}
```