# Solution to change a String date from form data to Date date in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I want to change the String date from form data to java Date format as I'm passing it to a class and making an object of the class later for storing.

Here's my code

**The form file**

```
<hr>
    <label for="firstname"><b>First Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="FirstName" required>

    <label for="middlename"><b>Middle Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Middle Name" name="MiddleName" required>

    <label for="lastname"><b>Last Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="LastName" required>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email" required>

    <label for="dob"><b>Enter Date of birth</b></label><br/>
    <input type="date" name="DOB" required><br/><br/>
```

**The jsp redirected file**

```
<%
        Employee obj = new Employee();
        obj.setFirstName(request.getParameter("FirstName"));
        obj.setMiddleName(request.getParameter("MiddleName"));
        obj.setLastName(request.getParameter("LastName"));
        //obj.setDob((String)request.getParameter("dob"));
        //**I wanna set the date here......**
        obj.setFirstName(request.getParameter("FirstName"));    
     %>
```

How can I go about through the problem. I'm currently building a Spring MVC web app.

Any suggestions or help are appreciated.
Thank you for the same.

Comment: First, the parameter is named `"DOB"` not `"dob"`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is the best, try that:

```
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse((String)request.getParameter("dob"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Java's newer `LocalDate` and its `parse` method. Using it is quite well described in [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate/%20this%20article).

If you really need a `Date` you can get it from the resulting `LocalDate`:

```
Date date = Date.from(localDate.toInstant());
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution for this would be to use Spring inbuilt annotation `@InitBinder` so that all the dates coming in complete controller will be automatically converted to the required format.You don't have to parse field by field manually.

```
@InitBinder
public final void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder, final Locale locale) {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", locale);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));    
}
```

Refer this thread to get more clarity on InitBinder.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211344/6572971