# Differences between @ExceptionHandler and @InitBinder and @ModelAttribute annotations in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I readed about **Spring in Action** book.Spring 3.2 brings another option to the table: controller advice. A controller advice is any class that’s annotated with @ControllerAdvice and has one or more of the following kinds of methods: @ExceptionHandler and @InitBinder and @ModelAttribute annotations.
Can you explain help me?

Answer (score 0):

`@ControllerAdvice` - Specialization of `@Component` for classes that declare `@ExceptionHandler`, `@InitBinder`, or `@ModelAttribute` methods to be shared across multiple @Controller classes.

For example, I use class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` to store multiple exception handlers, below is example code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException ex){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception ex){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex.getMessage());
    }


}
```

If You want read something about `@InitBinder` here is a excellent example

[Purpose of @InitBinder in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211323/what-is-the-purpose-of-init-binder-in-spring-mvc)

Annotation `@ModelAttribute` that binds a method parameter or method return value to a named model attribute, exposed to a web view. Supported for controller classes with @RequestMapping methods.

Example

```
@ModelAttribute("person")
public Person getPerson(){
    return new Person();
}
```

This annotated method allows you to access the Person object in your view layer as it is automatically added to models by Spring. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

`@ControllerAdvice` is an annotation provided by Spring allowing you to write global code that can be applied to a wide range of controllers
varying from all controllers to a chosen package or even a specific annotation.

By default, `@ControllerAdvice` will apply to all classes that use the `@Controller` annotation(which extends to classes using `@RestController`).
If you wanted this to be more specific, there are a few properties provided that allow this.

To reduce the applicable classes down by package, you simply need to add the name of the package to the annotation.
When a package is chosen, it will be enabled for classes inside that package as well as sub-packages.
Multiple packages can also be chosen by following the same process but using an array instead of a singular string (all properties in `@ControllerAdvice` can be singular or multiple).

```
@ControllerAdvice("my.chosen.package")
@ControllerAdvice(value = "my.chosen.package")
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "my.chosen.package")
```

To enable `@ControllerAdvice` for all controllers inside the package that the class (or interface) lives in.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = MyClass.class)
```

To apply to specific classes use assignableTypes.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = MyController.class)
```

If you want to apply it to controllers with certain annotations
The below snippet would only help controllers annotated with `@RestController` (which it covers by default) but will not include `@Controller` annotated classes.

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
```

[**Helpful Post for more insight**](https://dzone.com/articles/global-exception-handling-with-controlleradvice)

[[**Understanding Spring’s @ControllerAdvice**]](https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f)

[**Source Code**](https://github.com/lankydan/spring-boot-hateoas)

Comment: thanks you for your ask.